# number of time periods between the previous two periods where (non-zero) demand occurs in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the time interval of the last two periods of non-zero demand. The final column should be as shown in `nonzero_interval`. TIA.

edit: 
I've added a link to the paper where this question was motivated from.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'y': [34, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 10, 0],
    'nonzero_interval' : [np.nan, np. nan, 1,1,1,1,1,4,4,2]})

print(df)
```

The idea comes from [Forecasting Intermittent Demand Patterns with Time Seriesand Machine Learning Methodologies](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2f1e/dca7463b11b27a8de366c2889d47878ba27c.pdf)

Comment: The logic is not clear to me ..

Comment: @YOBEN_S I've added a link to the paper where this was used. The authors create a column for a non-zero time interval only on the last two known non-zero demand days. This is why there are times when the `nonzero_interval` appears to be cascading down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method from `numpy`

```
n=2
s=df[df.y.ne(0)].index
a=np.diag(s.values-s.values[:,None],k=n-1)
df['New']=pd.Series(a,index=s[n-1:])
df.New=df.New.shift(n-1).ffill()
df
    y  nonzero_interval  New
0  34               NaN  NaN
1  12               NaN  NaN
2   2               1.0  1.0
3   0               1.0  1.0
4   0               1.0  1.0
5   0               1.0  1.0
6  23               1.0  1.0
7   0               4.0  4.0
8  10               4.0  4.0
9   0               2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do it with `groupby.transform` with `count`, the groups are created where there are a value not equal to 0 with `cumsum`. then change where the values are equal to 0 to nan with `where`, `shift` and `ffill`.

```
df['nonzero_interval'] = (df.groupby(df['y'].ne(0).cumsum().shift())
                            ['y'].transform('count')
                            .where(df['y'].ne(0))
                            .shift().ffill()
                         )
print (df)
    y  nonzero_interval
0  34               NaN
1  12               NaN
2   2               1.0
3   0               1.0
4   0               1.0
5   0               1.0
6  23               1.0
7   0               4.0
8  10               4.0
9   0               2.0
```